# Angular failing to find components/services when using Angular Cli and Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular

I keep having this issue and I am unsure whether it is a problem with VS Code, Angular Cli or something else.
Basically if I create a component and then inject a service reference. In VS Code it might insert that reference like this:

```
import { QuestionService } from 'src/app/core/data/question.service';
```

And it will come back with an error like:

> src/app/widget/questions/questions.component.ts(5,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/core/data/question.service'.

But if I change it to:

```
import { QuestionService } from '../../core/data/question.service';
```

it will work fine. The only issue I have with doing it that way, is that I have to manually change each service reference and they are not always the same path (because it's relative).

Has anyone had this issue before? How do I solve it?

Comment: I had this issue before, I resolved it by cleaning my VSCode preferences and installing the latest version. I also changed the TSDK location to use the last version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way for solving this out is using a shorter alias name using the ts.config.
You can then point to any directory in your project and give it a custom namespace. Any name will work, but watch out for name collisions with existing node packages, i.e. @angular, @ngrx, etc. The end result looks like…

```
import { MyService } from '@services/my.service';

import { HelloWorldComponent } from '@components/hello-world.component';
```

// tsconfig.json in the root dir

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {

// omitted...

  "baseUrl": "src",
  "paths": {
    "@services/*": ["app/path/to/services/*"],
    "@components/*": ["app/somewhere/deeply/nested/*"],
    "@environments/*": ["environments/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/shorten-typescript-imports-in-an-angular-project/

Comment: Just found this myself :) looking into it, if it works I shall mark this as the answer